# Confusing memory report in Java sold process

Tags: linux, memory, solr, jvm, newrelic

I have a single solr server running in my server. The server has 14Gb RAM.

When I look in New Relic graphs, it appears that the amount of used memory in the server is around 3Gb:

[image]

When I execute the `htop` command I have a different result:

```
  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
17063 root       20   0 33.4G 12.5G 11.3G S 451. 88.8  1h17:59 java -jar start.jar
17430 root       20   0 33.4G 12.5G 11.3G R 97.8 88.8  2:30.47 java -jar start.jar
17456 root       20   0 33.4G 12.5G 11.3G R 96.4 88.8  1:07.96 java -jar start.jar
17457 root       20   0 33.4G 12.5G 11.3G R 94.0 88.8  1:33.25 java -jar start.jar
17459 root       20   0 33.4G 12.5G 11.3G R 82.1 88.8  2:34.93 java -jar start.jar
17431 root       20   0 33.4G 12.5G 11.3G R 69.8 88.8  3:35.84 java -jar start.jar
17065 root       20   0 33.4G 12.5G 11.3G S  0.9 88.8  0:05.35 java -jar start.jar
17067 root       20   0 33.4G 12.5G 11.3G S  0.9 88.8  0:05.40 java -jar start.jar
17069 root       20   0 33.4G 12.5G 11.3G S  0.9 88.8  0:05.37 java -jar start.jar
17072 root       20   0 33.4G 12.5G 11.3G S  0.9 88.8  0:05.37 java -jar start.jar
17075 root       20   0 33.4G 12.5G 11.3G S  0.9 88.8  0:05.37 java -jar start.jar
17077 root       20   0 33.4G 12.5G 11.3G S  0.9 88.8  0:05.33 java -jar start.jar
17066 root       20   0 33.4G 12.5G 11.3G S  0.9 88.8  0:05.42 java -jar start.jar
17068 root       20   0 33.4G 12.5G 11.3G S  0.9 88.8  0:05.46 java -jar start.jar
17073 root       20   0 33.4G 12.5G 11.3G S  0.9 88.8  0:05.25 java -jar start.jar
17074 root       20   0 33.4G 12.5G 11.3G S  0.9 88.8  0:05.33 java -jar start.jar
17070 root       20   0 33.4G 12.5G 11.3G S  0.5 88.8  0:05.27 java -jar start.jar
17076 root       20   0 33.4G 12.5G 11.3G S  0.5 88.8  0:05.42 java -jar start.jar
17071 root       20   0 33.4G 12.5G 11.3G S  0.5 88.8  0:05.37 java -jar start.jar
17078 root       20   0 33.4G 12.5G 11.3G S  0.5 88.8  0:01.42 java -jar start.jar
```

Why `htop` says the process is consuming 11.3Gb?

And the `free` cmd:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      14779804   14258740     521064        360      10628   12114752
-/+ buffers/cache:    2133360   12646444
Swap:            0          0          0
```

And the New Relic java process memory usage:

[image]

How much memory is my process really using? Why New Relic shows 3Gb for the whole server and 13Gb for the java process?

Answer (score 1):

You can find information about this at New Relic's Forum

https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/why-do-free-and-or-top-show-different-memory-usage-than-the-new-relic-ui/273

As for the individual process, New Relic's Linux Server Monitor (LSM) is not designed to run as the root user. Since Linux uses a [copy on write virtual memory scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) and non-root users have limited access to information about memory shared between processes, memory which is shared between processes is re-counted for each process that LSM queries. The result is an unexpectedly large total memory usage reflected in the New Relic user interface for affected processes. 
The total memory usage you see in the system overview tab is reported by the Linux kernel which has full access to information about memory shared between process and this number should accurately reflect the real total memory used on your machine.